# How to get values of keys for changing Json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am using python2.7

I have a json i pull that is always changing when i request it.

I need to pull out `Animal_Target_DisplayNam`e under Term7 Under Relation6 in my dict.

The problem is sometimes the object Relation6 is in another part of the Json, it could be leveled deeper or in another order.

I am trying to create code that can just export the values of the key `Animal_Target_DisplayName` but nothing is working. It wont even loop down the nested dict.

Now this can work if i just pull it out using something like `['view']['Term0'][0]['Relation6']` but remember the JSON is never returned in the same structure.

Code i am using to get the values of the key `Animal_Target_DisplayName` but it doesnt seem to loop through my dict and find all the values with that key.

```
array = []
for d in dict.values():
    row = d['Animal_Target_DisplayName']
    array.append(row)
```

JSON Below:

```
dict = {  
   "view":{  
      "Term0":[  
         {  
            "Id":"b0987b91-af12-4fe3-a56f-152ac7a4d84d",
            "DisplayName":"Dog",
            "FullName":"Dog",
            "AssetType1":[  
               {  
                  "AssetType_Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031131",
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":"ee74a59d-fb74-4052-97ba-9752154f015d",
            "DisplayName":"Dog2",
            "FullName":"Dog",
            "AssetType1":[  
               {  
                  "AssetType_Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031131",
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":"eb548eae-da6f-41e8-80ea-7e9984f56af6",
            "DisplayName":"Dog3",
            "FullName":"Dog3",
            "AssetType1":[  
               {  
                  "AssetType_Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031131",
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":"cfac6dd4-0efa-4417-a2bf-0333204f8a42",
            "DisplayName":"Animal Set",
            "FullName":"Animal Set",
            "AssetType1":[  
               {  
                  "AssetType_Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0001-000400000001",
               }
            ],
            "StringAttribute2":[  
               {  
                  "StringAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000003114_Id":"00a701a8-be4c-4b76-a6e5-3b0a4085bcc8",
                  "StringAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000003114_Value":"Desc"
               }
            ],
            "StringAttribute3":[  
               {  
                  "StringAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000262_Id":"a81adfb4-7528-4673-8c95-953888f3b43a",
                  "StringAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000262_Value":"meow"
               }
            ],
            "BooleanAttribute4":[  
               {  
                  "BooleanAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0001-000500000001_Id":"932c5f97-c03f-4a1a-a0c5-a518f5edef5e",
                  "BooleanAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0001-000500000001_Value":"true"
               }
            ],
            "SingleValueListAttribute5":[  
               {  
                  "SingleValueListAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0001-000500000031_Id":"ef51dedd-6f25-4408-99a6-5a6cfa13e198",
                  "SingleValueListAttribute_00000000-0000-0000-0001-000500000031_Value":"Blah"
               }
            ],
            "Relation6":[  
               {  
                  "Animal_Id":"2715ca09-3ced-4b74-a418-cef4a95dddf1",
                  "Term7":[  
                     {  
                        "Animal_Target_Id":"88fd0090-4ea8-4ae6-b7f0-1b13e5cf3d74",
                        "Animal_Target_DisplayName":"Animaltheater",
                        "Animal_Target_FullName":"Animaltheater"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "Animal_Id":"6068fe78-fc8e-4542-9aee-7b4b68760dcd",
                  "Term7":[  
                     {  
                        "Animal_Target_Id":"4e87a614-2a8b-46c0-90f3-8a0cf9bda66c",
                        "Animal_Target_DisplayName":"Animaltitle",
                        "Animal_Target_FullName":"Animaltitle"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "Animal_Id":"754ec0e6-19b6-4b6b-8ba1-573393268257",
                  "Term7":[  
                     {  
                        "Animal_Target_Id":"a8986ed5-3ec8-44f3-954c-71cacb280ace",
                        "Animal_Target_DisplayName":"Animalcustomer",
                        "Animal_Target_FullName":"Animalcustomer"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "Animal_Id":"86b3ffd1-4d54-4a98-b25b-369060651bd6",
                  "Term7":[  
                     {  
                        "Animal_Target_Id":"89d02067-ebe8-4b87-9a1f-a6a0bdd40ec4",
                        "Animal_Target_DisplayName":"Animalfact_transaction",
                        "Animal_Target_FullName":"Animalfact_transaction"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "Animal_Id":"ea2e1b76-f8bc-46d9-8ebc-44ffdd60f213",
                  "Term7":[  
                     {  
                        "Animal_Target_Id":"e398cd32-1e73-46bd-8b8f-d039986d6de0",
                        "Animal_Target_DisplayName":"Animalfact_transaction",
                        "Animal_Target_FullName":"Animalfact_transaction"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "Relation10":[  
               {  
                  "TargetRelation_b8b178ff-e957-47db-a4e7-6e5b789d6f03_Id":"aff80bd0-a282-4cf5-bdcc-2bad35ddec1d",
                  "Term11":[  
                     {  
                        "AnimalId":"3ac22167-eb91-469a-9d94-315aa301f55a",
                        "AnimalDisplayName":"Animal",
                        "AnimalFullName":"Animal"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "Tag12":[  
               {  
                  "Tag_Id":"75968ea6-4c9f-43c9-80f7-dfc41b24ec8f",
                  "Tag_Name":"AnimalAnimaltitle"
               },
               {  
                  "Tag_Id":"b1adbc00-aeef-415b-82b6-a3159145c60d",
                  "Tag_Name":"Animal2"
               },
               {  
                  "Tag_Id":"5f78e4dc-2b37-41e0-a0d3-cec773af2397",
                  "Tag_Name":"AnimalDisplayName"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The output i am trying to get is a list of all the values from key `Animal_Target_DisplayName` like this `['Animaltheater','Animaltitle', 'Animalcustomer', 'Animalfact_transaction', 'Animalfact_transaction']` but we need to remember the nested structure of this json always changes but the keys for it are always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your only option is running through the entire dict and get the values of `Animal_Target_DisplayName` key, I propose the following recursive solution:

```py
def run_json(dict_):
    animal_target_sons = []
    if type(dict_) is list:
        for element in dict_:
            animal_target_sons.append(run_json(element)) 
    elif type(dict_) is dict:
        for key in dict_:
            if key=="Animal_Target_DisplayName":
                animal_target_sons.append([dict_[key]])
            else:
                animal_target_sons.append(run_json(dict_[key]))
    return [x for sublist in animal_target_sons for x in sublist]
run_json(dict_)
```

Then calling `run_json` returns a list with what you want. By the way, I recommend you to rename your json from `dict` to, for example `dict_`, since `dict` is a reserved word of Python for the dictionary type.

Comment: Is there a method to doing this without using global variable? Can i just make it return an array?

Comment: Everytime i call this function it keeps the old data. How do i clear it?

Comment: Sure, checkout my new response ;)

Answer (score -1):

Since you're getting JSON, why not make use of the json module? That will do the parsing for you and allow you to use dictionary functions+features to get the information you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from __future__ import print_function
import json

# _somehow_ get your JSON in as a string. I'm calling it "jstr" for this 
# example. 
# Use the module to parse it 
jdict = json.loads(jstr)

# our dict has keys...
# view -> Term0 -> keys-we're-interested-in

templist = jdict["view"]["Term0"]

results = {}

for _el in range(len(templist)):
    if templist[_el]["FullName"] == "Animal Set":
        # this is the one we're interested in - and it's another list
        moretemp = templist[_el]["Relation6"]
        for _k in range(len(moretemp)):
            term7 = moretemp[_k]["Term7"][0]
            displayName = term7["Animal_Target_DisplayName"]
            fullName = term7["Animal_Target_FullName"]
            results[fullName] = displayName
print("{0}".format(results))
```

Then you can dump the `results` dict plain, or with pretty-printing:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
{
    "Animaltitle2": "Animaltitle2", 
    "Animalcustomer3": "Animalcustomer3", 
    "Animalfact_transaction4": "Animalfact_transaction4", 
    "Animaltheater1": "Animaltheater1"
}
```